# Editing my Bash prompt

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, prompt

I'd like to put something into my bash prompt, but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

I use the Cloud Foundry Command Line Tool to push code up to my servers. The `cf` tool can be set to a specific ORG or another, and within each set to a specific SPACE ('development' or 'production' for example).

Currently my bash prompt looks like this:

```
~/projects/timer/website
 (bug3) $
```

It's actually colored quite a bit more nicely than than : ) 'bug3' is a git branch, and if I had done any work, there'd even be an asterisks 'bug3*' to denote my git status.

If I run `cf target -s production` I get some output:

```
API endpoint:   https://api[dot]domain[dot]com (API version: 4.10.1)   
User:           costa[at]domain[dot]com   
Org:            IB   
Space:          Production
```

I want to get the bash prompt looking like this:

```
~/projects/timer/website
 (bug3) IB-Production $
```

How might I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your `~/.bashrc` file and add this at the end:

```
function cfinfo(){
  cf target | awk '$1=="Org:"{printf "%s-", $2} $1=="Space:"{print $2}'
}
```

That function generates the string `IB-Production` depending on the output of the command `cf target -s production`.

Then add this after that function definition in `~/.bashrc`:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w \n $(cfinfo) \$ '
```

**Notice:** The part before `$(cfinfo)` differs in your case. In my example it is just the default uncolored debian prompt.

Comment: Hmmm... how would I get it to display only if the current directory has a cf project (or alternatively, a git repo?)

Comment: I'm doing: 

`function cfinfo(){
  if [ -d .git ]; then
    cf target | awk '$1=="Org:"{printf "%s-", $2} $1=="Space:"{print $2}'
  fi
}`